# How to use where clause in eloquent relationships in laravel

Tags: laravel, foreign-keys, relationship

I'm trying to access company variable in laravel eloquent relationship but i'm getting error undefined variable.

Controller

```
$assignedCases = AddressCaseAssign::with(['addresses' => function ($query) {
                                $query->where('company_id', '=',$request->company);

                            }])->where('user_id',$request->executive)
                            ->get();
```

Model

```
public function addresses(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Address::class,'address_id');
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `$request` in where clause using `use` keyword:

```
$assignedCases = AddressCaseAssign::with(['addresses' => function ($query) use ($request) {
                            $query->where('company_id', '=',$request->company);

                        }])->where('user_id',$request->executive)
                        ->get();
```

Comment: Great! That's wokring